# Terminal is not working as usual mac after trying to install CakePHP

Tags: bash, macos, shell, cakephp, path

I was downloading the CakePHP framework for a project. Below the steps:
Installation
1) Install PHP 5.6 from: http://php-osx.liip.ch/

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

2) add the updated PHP version to our path. So we edit .profile file

```
nano ~/.profile
```

Add into the file

```
export PATH= /usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Then hit Control + O to write out the file
Then hit Control + X to save the file

`exit`

Restart the Terminal

Now the terminal doesn't work as usually. I've tried to understand the shell concept and apply different solutions, but I can't even find the .profile file again.

I obtain errors like:

`enter code here`-bash: ls: command not found

Anybody can explain me what's wrong and the shell concept to properly understand shell (-bash)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
export PATH= /usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

You killed your PATH variable. You need to find a way to edit `.profile` file, and change that line to:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/php5/bin
```

You could try editing with the following command (using `vim`):

```
/usr/bin/vim /Users/yourname/.profile
```

Or (using `nano`):

```
/usr/bin/nano /Users/yourname/.profile
```

Or just remove `.profile` file completely by doing `/bin/rm /Users/yourname/.profile`. Of course, in any case, you need to restart your terminal once you're done.